# Always Using Maven `clean` Goal?

Tags: java, maven

Should the Maven `clean` goal be applied to every build as a best practice to avoid stale CLASS files? Or perhaps always using `clean` is unnecessary since Maven is smart enough to know which source code needs to be re-compiled based on changes?

- compile
- install
- etc?

Gareth Davis pointed out the potential danger of forgetting to running a `clean` after re-naming a CLASS file - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4662536/409976.

Example:

1. Compile module (not whole project) - Foo.java -> target/Foo.class
2. Re-name to Bar.java & re-compile module -> target/{Foo.class, Bar.class}
3. re-compile `main`
4. BOOM – other module code should’ve failed to compile since it relied on making a Foo class (but it still longer exists since we didn’t clean).

I'm looking into whether the absence of `clean` will improve build performance on a guest VM within a shared directory. However, I'm not aware of all of the consequences of **not** always calling the `clean` step first.

Comment: Maybe you should edit the question to ask for canonical answers or answers from official sources.

Comment: Is this in the context of your IDE or of your build?

Comment: in the context of build from command-line

Comment: I once had a 40MB ear file and without checking I uploaded it to the server after mvn-install in Eclipse. It was acting so weird and I spent days trying to figure out what was wrong until I saw the size was 80MB. I tell you doing "cleaning" is always good. I just don't trust maven+eclipse ever since together. Now I do "clean" before "install" all day long.

Answer (score 8):

Running `clean` before any build is always a good practice since the stale class scenario that you have mentioned is completely possible and if encountered, it can create problems in your final artifact.

> I'm looking into whether the absence of clean will improve build performance on a guest VM.

By performance, my best guess is that you mean time efficiency. By avoiding the clean goal, you CAN save time since maven will only build the classes where any change was done and it will leave out the rest of the untouched class. So, technically speaking, yes you will save some time in the build process.

> However, I'm not aware of all of the consequences of not always calling the clean step first.

Class staleness is by far the most common issue that you may and will encounter.

By experience I can share a couple of things. If you are using an IDE and your project structure is a bit large complex ( A couple of dependant modules etc etc ) then running `mvn clean` does sometimes confuse the IDE in managing the build path of the project and you may run into `ClassNotFoundException`s. Although not a big issue but you have to do a project --> maven --> Update project to set the build path right.

(Edit However, if you are running it via command lien, then this issue will never arise)

On your dev machines, its all good with `mvn install`, but when you are deploying a build on production or test server, its best to go with `mvn clean` before doing a `mvn install` to make sure no issues arise and all the classes are built once before wrapping them in a jar/war or anything

Comment: Having proper release management in place should take the responsibility to have to do clean install from you though. Example: use the Maven release plugin (or let something like Hudson manage that for you) in stead of manually building the deployable test/acceptance/production artifacts.

Comment: Nice addition to the post @Gimby. Good remarks about using release management tools for automating