# Clean lifecycle in Travis CI Maven build

Tags: maven, travis-ci, maven-lifecycle, maven-clean-plugin

When I review `.travis.yml` configs I very often see [`mvn clean verify`](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22mvn+clean+verify%22+filename%3A.travis.yml&type=Code&ref=searchresults) or [`mvn clean install`](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22mvn+clean+install%22+filename%3A.travis.yml&type=Code&ref=searchresults).

Is there any point in invoking `clean` lifecycle in the Travis CI builds when it is first invocation of `mvn` in script? Are there any cases when `clean` might be necessary in fresh Travis build that has just started?

I understand why `clean` is needed in local environment when the state might not be clean, so [In Maven, Why Run 'mvn clean'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662452/in-maven-why-run-mvn-clean) does not answer my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Maven, Why Run 'mvn clean'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662452/in-maven-why-run-mvn-clean)

Comment: @A.DiMatteo please see edit I've made. My question is different.

Comment: Usually travis-ci builds are always fresh builds (docker containers) so usually it does not make really sense to do `mvn clean ...`...

Comment: It could protect against generated files that have been inadvertently committed to the repository.