# Have to mvn clean install every time I'm modifying my code

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm not from the Java world but i've to dig into it for one of my projects. I don't understand why everytime i'm modiyfing or updating my code, have to mvn clean install to debug the last version of my code. 
Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: That depends on how you're running your app. If it's integrated in your IDE, I expect it to take changes into account and compile on the fly and you can debug safely. However, if you're debugging remotely, then that's normal: you need to compile explicitly yourself so that the changes that you made are in effect. Either way, the code has to be compiled at some point.

Comment: Bear in mind that Java needs to be compiled to byte code before being run by the JVM, unlike fully interpreted languages like Python. the `clean` part of `mvn clean install` gets rid of anything already compiled so you know you're always starting from a known "clean" state. Here's some more background: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4662537/212224

Answer (score 3):

try to press `Ctrl+Shift+F9` (hot swap), sometimes it helps

Answer (score 2):

When using intellij, you have no save button.

So you should build manually (Ctrl + F9 ) or change the settings :

**Settings/Preferences **->**  Build, Execution, Deployment **->** Compiler** 
and select the **Make project automatically** option

cf [Intellij Website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/eclipse.html#workflows)