# Springboot application can't run without execute the 'mvn clean' command

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

Hi， recently I encountered a very wired problem in my springboot application. When I tried to run my application, it can't run. However, after I execute 'mvn clean' command, it can run successfully. And this happens not just one or two times, it happens everytime when I tried to run the springboot application, which makes me have to execute 'mvn clean' each time I want to run this application.Here is the stack trace:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-03-16 11:25:09.657 ERROR 24896 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'locationController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'addrService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'addressMapperImpl' defined in file [/Users/xzp/Desktop/trace/trace-dao/target/classes/com/trace/dao/impl/AddressMapperImpl 2.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'file [/Users/xzp/Desktop/trace/trace-dao/target/classes/mapper/AddressMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'file [/Users/xzp/Desktop/trace/trace-dao/target/classes/mapper/AddressMapper.xml]'. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection already contains value for com.trace.dao.repository.AddressMapper.BaseResultMap
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.trace.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'addrService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'addressMapperImpl' defined in file [/Users/xzp/Desktop/trace/trace-dao/target/classes/com/trace/dao/impl/AddressMapperImpl 2.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'file [/Users/xzp/Desktop/trace/trace-dao/target/classes/mapper/AddressMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'file [/Users/xzp/Desktop/trace/trace-dao/target/classes/mapper/AddressMapper.xml]'. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection already contains value for com.trace.dao.repository.AddressMapper.BaseResultMap
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'addressMapperImpl' defined in file [/Users/xzp/Desktop/trace/trace-dao/target/classes/com/trace/dao/impl/AddressMapperImpl 2.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'file [/Users/xzp/Desktop/trace/trace-dao/target/classes/mapper/AddressMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'file [/Users/xzp/Desktop/trace/trace-dao/target/classes/mapper/AddressMapper.xml]'. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection already contains value for com.trace.dao.repository.AddressMapper.BaseResultMap
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'file [/Users/xzp/Desktop/trace/trace-dao/target/classes/mapper/AddressMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'file [/Users/xzp/Desktop/trace/trace-dao/target/classes/mapper/AddressMapper.xml]'. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection already contains value for com.trace.dao.repository.AddressMapper.BaseResultMap
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'file [/Users/xzp/Desktop/trace/trace-dao/target/classes/mapper/AddressMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'file [/Users/xzp/Desktop/trace/trace-dao/target/classes/mapper/AddressMapper.xml]'. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection already contains value for com.trace.dao.repository.AddressMapper.BaseResultMap
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'file [/Users/xzp/Desktop/trace/trace-dao/target/classes/mapper/AddressMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'file [/Users/xzp/Desktop/trace/trace-dao/target/classes/mapper/AddressMapper.xml]'. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection already contains value for com.trace.dao.repository.AddressMapper.BaseResultMap
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    ... 74 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'file [/Users/xzp/Desktop/trace/trace-dao/target/classes/mapper/AddressMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'file [/Users/xzp/Desktop/trace/trace-dao/target/classes/mapper/AddressMapper.xml]'. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection already contains value for com.trace.dao.repository.AddressMapper.BaseResultMap
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:613) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:491) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:633) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration.sqlSessionFactory(MybatisAutoConfiguration.java:179) ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
    at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4f934a05.CGLIB$sqlSessionFactory$2(<generated>) ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
    at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4f934a05$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$608feeec.invoke(<generated>) ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4f934a05.sqlSessionFactory(<generated>) ~[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    ... 75 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'file [/Users/xzp/Desktop/trace/trace-dao/target/classes/mapper/AddressMapper.xml]'. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection already contains value for com.trace.dao.repository.AddressMapper.BaseResultMap
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.configurationElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:120) ~[mybatis-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.parse(XMLMapperBuilder.java:92) ~[mybatis-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:611) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    ... 88 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection already contains value for com.trace.dao.repository.AddressMapper.BaseResultMap
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration$StrictMap.put(Configuration.java:872) ~[mybatis-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration$StrictMap.put(Configuration.java:844) ~[mybatis-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.addResultMap(Configuration.java:626) ~[mybatis-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.MapperBuilderAssistant.addResultMap(MapperBuilderAssistant.java:214) ~[mybatis-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.ResultMapResolver.resolve(ResultMapResolver.java:47) ~[mybatis-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.resultMapElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:285) ~[mybatis-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.resultMapElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:252) ~[mybatis-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.resultMapElements(XMLMapperBuilder.java:244) ~[mybatis-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.configurationElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:116) ~[mybatis-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    ... 90 common frames omitted
```

I use mybatis in my project. I feel so wired about this problem. I can successfully deploy the .jar package using 'java -jar' command, but I just can't run in idea.

Comment: My guess is that it's something about your iBatis XML that doesn't play nice with what IntelliJ produces when it runs your app.  Hard to know though without digging into your XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because of some reason the auto-clean is not enabled in the POM file.

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>auto-clean</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Try using this in pom file and it also can be because of the eclipse is not getting auto clean ,
For this you can set a  Provide Goal: `mvn clean install` and then run it .
For this

- Right click on Project
- Click on Maven
- Click on Update Project...
- Right click on project
- Click on Run As
- Click on Maven build...
- Provide Goal: mvn clean install
- Select checkbox for Skip Tests
- Click Apply and Run

Answer (score 0):

In my app i solve it by:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might check [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847619/have-to-mvn-clean-install-every-time-im-modifying-my-code) they said about hot swap. I had the same issue on Eclipse when 'Build Automatically' is unchecked