# Is it necessary to execute mvn clean before mvn compile?

Tags: java, maven

If I want to re-compile the project, should I execute mvn clean first?

Comment: In theory, no.  In practice, often yes.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I see a lot `mvn clean compile`, why?

Comment: no but i suggest clean

Comment: Just make `mvn package` that's it...clean is usually not needed...only very rare situations...

Comment: Do a build with clean and a build without clean. Do you notice a difference? Probably the difference is so small that you don't even notice it. Building from a clean slate in maven is simply a good idea. Incremental building is generally something you do from an IDE.

Comment: @Gimby without clean build takes less than 10 secs..with clean it takes about 30 seconds......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most of the cases you can skip `clean`. However you should keep in mind possible side effects can be caused by "dirty" target directory. E.g.

- You completely removed some class/file, compiled version gonna live in target
- In real life project it is quite often to use external plugins during the build, which can also generate some files/reports/etc. From my experience plugin developers don't care a lot to handle situations with "dirty" target folder (I would do the same :)), so you can get tricky errors during the build.

So I would highly recommend to **always** use clean:

- Before publishing the artifacts
- When you get some unexpected behavior/errors during compile/package

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time yes,

When deleting resources, classes or anything which lead to something created in the target directory then a clean is necessary because the item won't be deleted until then.

If not, the generated artifacts may contain those deleted items.

If you only updated existing items then most of the time you can bypass the clean

EDIT:

Be extra careful with my last statement. Even updates can lead to side effects without clean. What if a plugin generates items with hash in their names ?

@See [In Maven, Why Run 'mvn clean'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662452/in-maven-why-run-mvn-clean) for more issues than can arise without clean