# What jar files are deployed to Google appengine

Tags: maven, google-app-engine

I use maven to package and deploy my Google Appengine and all associated front-end & back-end files. I noticed in the war file there were multiple versions of the same java libraries, e.g. `google-api-client-appengine-1.30.jar`, there was also `1.31` and `1.32`. I don't have or need a dependency on this jar file, so maven is grabbing the latest, but doesn't remove the older versions. I obviously needed a clean up. After running `mvn clean`, my set of libraries was a lot smaller and cleaner.

However, when I deployed the app again it reported:
`[INFO] GCLOUD: #= Uploading 1 file to Google Cloud Storage  =#`
which was just my changelog.html file.

How do I know which jar files are deployed and which versions of the jar files the code is actually running/using?
Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 1):

You can choose which version of a library you want in a maven project by specifying it in the `pom.xml` file. For App Engine is the same, [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/using-maven#adding_the_maven_plugin) is an example of how adding App Engine Maven plugin to it looks.

If you didn't specify a version maven will automatically grab the latest one. You can check which version of each dependency will be used by running this command:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Please note that this command will show which versions will be used if you were to run `mvn package` at that moment.

Lastly, even thought in most cases is safe to skip `clean` this isn't recommended, you should use it in order to keep the target directory clean, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49769317/12512650).

Comment: I have that plugin, and I am specifying versions of key libraries in my pom.xml file. For some libraries I don't need a specific version and am happy for Maven to grab the latest, but if I don't do a clean every time then sometimes there are two (or more) versions. Just wanted to know how I can tell which version is actually being used.