# maven, source still can be found in target folder even delete in src/main/java inside eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I already delete a source abc.java in proj1/src/main/java inside eclipse, and I have set build automatically in eclipse, but I still find it in target/proj1-snapshot/main/java/....

why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Maven, Why Run 'mvn clean'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662452/in-maven-why-run-mvn-clean)